# Value still = 0?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I am working on a game programmed with batch, but for some reason the %wood% value stays 0 whenever I add 2 to it. I tried to fix it, but I couldn't and I came here to solve the problem. Does anyboyd know how to fix this? Did I make a error or...

Here is the source code:

```
@echo off
title CommandCraft bg tst ns a. 1.01
color 2
echo W  W  W EEEE
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
echo W  W  W E
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
echo W  W  W EEEE
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
echo W  W  W E
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
echo WWWWWWW EEEE
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
echo Presents
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul
cls
color 7
echo CommandCraft! (Version: bg tst ns a. 1.01)
echo.
echo Press any key to start
pause > nul
cls
:restart
set wood=0
set ore=0
set metal=0
echo You are in a forest.
:start
echo What do you do?
set /p action=Command?
if %action% == chop goto chop
if %action% == inventory goto items
:cmdelse
echo %action% is not a valid action.
goto start
:chop
echo You gained 2 peices of wood
set /a res = %wood% + 2
set %wood% = res
echo You now have %wood% peices of wood
goto start
:items
echo You have Wood x %wood%
echo You have Metal Ore x %ore%
echo You have Metal x %metal% 
goto start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set %wood%=res
```

should be changed to

```
set /a wood=%res%
```

. This is a common error done by many people, so make sure to check your syntax at the important lines, and then [debugging the code](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-software-debugging-methods), before posting a question! ;)

Plus, you can just do

```
set /a wood+=2
```

because it works as much as

```
set /a res=%wood%+2
set wood=%res%
```

and saves precious lines (lines *are* precious in the poor readability of Batch scripts), since you only need to assign one variable. It also saves memory which is just as precious...

Other than that, nice game!

EDIT: Thanks for pointing out in the comments. It has been some time since the last time I used Batch :P

Comment: `set /a` doesn't even need the `%`: `set /a wood=wood+2` works fine. Also to add something to a variable there is a short form: `set /a wood +=2`

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: `set wood = %res%` will set a variable "wood[space]" to "[space][the content of res]". "set wood = %wood% + 2" will set  a variable "wood[space]" to "[space][the content of wood][space]+[space]2". The `/a` is critical - `set /a` semantics disregard spaces.

Comment: Stephan and Magoo : you're right! Thanks for pointing out :)

In fact it has been quite some time since I used batch :P